# Arabic text is appearing as "?????" in Wordpress

Tags: html, mysql, css, wordpress

In `wp-config.php` I have the charset defined as follows

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
```

In the header I have `meta` with charset defined as follows

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

In `style.css` I had `@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";` but I changed it to `@CHARSET "UTF-8";`

When I write directly into a template page using Arabic and view it, it always appears as question marks `?????`

But this is only when I write text directly into the template file. I have other strings stored in the database and using [qTranslate-X plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/), Arabic appears fine.

I have also tried the following instead of writing text directly.

```
__('arabic text here');

_e('arabic text here');
```

None of it worked.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `DB_CHARSET` to utf-8: `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`.

My only guess right now is that you are having some output skewed by an inconsistency in the encoding.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean `DB_CHARSET` change or addition. I went to the header, got rid of `bloginfo( 'charset' );` and replaced it with `UTF-8` - it's still not working.

Comment: If you added `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` there is more room for you having made a configuration error. If `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` is defined by wordpress, and you simply changed its value, I can assume its correct

Comment: no I didn't add it, it came with the Wordpress' installation by default. I tried changing it to `UTF-8` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Let's keep the wordpress default instead of overriding that with a hardcoded value. Have a look at your web source and see if your `<meta charset="utf-8">` (or similar) is there

Comment: yes it shows `<meta charset="utf-8">` and in the table `wp_options` the `blog_charset` is `UTF-8`

Comment: Are you then able to read from your database directly through command line or something like phpmyadmin and check whether your input was saved as questionmarks?

Comment: This string is not saved in the database, I am writing it directly into the template file like this `<h1>Arabic text here</h1>` However, other arabic texts in the database are working normally, can read them just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114428/discussion-between-jonathan-and-halnex).